# Loop through local files to perform a user-defined function

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to loop a function through local files. The file structure is (.../Project/data/company_name/date) There are many different company_name folders each containing many date files.

The function has two arguments, input file path and output file path. Currently my best idea is:

```
    for FILE in os.getcwd():
        scraper.scrape('.../Project/data/*/*.html', '.../Project/data/*/*.txt')
```

Getting 'OSError: Invalid argument' as a result due to the syntax of my file paths, probably something to do with the * where I am trying to allow the loop to seek the various company folders and documents within each folder. Any ideas on how to improve this would be appreciated!!

Comment: scraper.scrape(...) throws the exception? Your call is independent of FILE. Check [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) which might help you.

Comment: You are looping over the *characters* in the *name* of the current working directory.  Presumably you want to loop over *files*, which would be `os.listdir()`.  Of course, it doesn't matter what you are looping over as long as you aren't using `FILE` for anything.